# Is "transfigurā penitus" the proper conjugation of the verb "transfiguro" in the context of a motto to mean "change internally"?

Tags: motto

I am trying to describe the internal change which takes place as a person gets older or goes through a spiritual process. *transfiguro* and *penitus* are the best words I can find, *transfigurā penitus* is my best guess at the proper conjugation for a slogan or motto.

Answer (score 2):

Transfigura would not be ideal as transfiguro is a transitive verb. I would suggest the passive imperative -
'Penitus transfigurare'- Be transformed within.
Or you could use muto (I change) instead of transfiguro, giving
'Penitus mutare',
which is more concise and perhaps therefore more suitable for a motto.